# "No seu agrado" ou "do seu agrado"?

Tags: expressões, sintaxe, preposições

Esses dias eu estava escrevendo um texto e, no final, eu gostaria de perguntar para o cliente se o resultado satisfazia-o. Eu ia utilizar a frase “Está no seu agrado?”, mas eu fiquei em dúvida se devemos realmente utilizar ***no*** ou ***do***. Portanto, qual das duas frases abaixo está correta:

> Está no seu agrado?

ou

> Está do seu agrado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Estar no seu agrado* até faz sentido, mas a expressão consagrada é ***estar do seu agrado***; consagrada quer no uso popular, pelo menos em Portugal (é o que eu sempre ouvi), quer na literatura (portuguesa e brasileira), como se pode ver no [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1366&bih=625&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk020qIAEC0_rAEX0sHQSk8ckQ3H10w%3A1593703243606&ei=S_v9XqTIJI2bjLsP1au6oAI&q=%22estava%20do%20seu%20agrado%22&oq=%22estava%20do%20seu%20agrado%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...5087.5392.0.6559.2.2.0.0.0.0.108.201.1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.pjcaIGad2J8).

A lógica pode ver-se na seguinte comparação:

> *Feijoada é ___ seu agrado?* versus *A feijoada está ___ seu agrado?*

As duas construções são paralelas: num caso pergunta-se se a pessoa gosta de feijoada em geral; no outro se gosta daquela feijoada em particular. Faz sentido que a preposição seja a mesma nos dois casos, e no primeiro só pode ser ***do***.

Mas já houve quem escrevesse *estar no agrado*, [aqui em 1887](https://books.google.pt/books?id=JZdRAQAAMAAJ&q=%22est%C3%A1%20no%20agrado%22&dq=%22est%C3%A1%20no%20agrado%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwim8YiHra7qAhWRTsAKHeZgBlcQ6AEwBnoECAEQAg) e [aqui em 1905](https://books.google.pt/books?id=6n5QAQAAMAAJ&q=%22est%C3%A1%20no%20agrado%22&dq=%22est%C3%A1%20no%20agrado%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwim8YiHra7qAhWRTsAKHeZgBlcQ6AEwBHoECAQQAg), aparentemente com o mesmo significado de *estar do agrado* (gostaria de ver mais contexto para ter a certeza). Também usamos *em* na expressão [*cair **no** agrado de alguém*](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1366&bih=625&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk02AJVfhebazRiT2NuC0R1SNL5Nccg%3A1593703251185&ei=U_v9Xp34CsafjLsPyr-qqAI&q=%22caiu%20no%20agrado%22&oq=%22caiu%20no%20agrado%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...116850.119702.0.120529.8.8.0.0.0.0.130.628.6j1.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.i24JsNuRUKQ). Aqui tem mesmo de ser *no*; *cair do agrado de alguém* significaria quando muito o oposto.

Ambos os casos podem ser vistos como uma metáfora espacial: voltando ao primeiro exemplo, podemos imaginar cada variante possível da feijoada como um ponto num espaço; um subconjunto desse espaço é do meu agrado; e uma feijoada em particular é um ponto que pode estar ou não nesse subconjunto.

Encontrei no Google Books também foi uns tantos [*estar **ao** seu agrado*](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1366&bih=625&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk01KxKJdR2Co5lQm-UCU56O5lZUlAQ%3A1593687145969&ei=abz9XsjfOtKO1fAPp6SP4Ag&q=%22est%C3%A1%20ao%20agrado%22&oq=%22est%C3%A1%20ao%20agrado%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...7787.11074.0.12012.4.4.0.0.0.0.807.1163.0j3j6-1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.HI-R6mQC3QA), o que também faz sentido, já que dizemos *estar ao seu gosto*.

Comment: Muito obrigado, Jacinto. Pensei que só houvesse uma possibilidade nessa expressão, mas pelo visto, existem três. Agregou bastante ao meu conhecimento!

Comment: @Chanp, sempre às ordens. Existem três, que é como quem diz... *estar no agrado* compreende-se, é possível encontrar-lhe uma lógica e (possivelmente por isso mesmo) já houve quem escrevesse; mas é marginal; o que está mesmo consagrado pelo uso é *estar do agrado*.